# Group By Column Alias

Tags: sql, database, group-by, case

I want to group an sql statement by a column alias. In essense, I want the below to function as it should logically, but grouping by a column created with an as is not allowed. (Invalid column name). Anyone got any tips?

```
SELECT 
    CASE
    WHEN Date IS NULL
    THEN 'EMPTY'
    ELSE
        CASE
        WHEN Date = '1/1/1753'
        THEN 'UNAVAILABLE'
        ELSE CAST(MONTH(Date) as varchar(MAX))+
             '/'+ CAST(YEAR(Date) as varchar(MAX))
        END
    END AS MonthYear
FROM tbltablename
GROUP BY MonthYear
```

Comment: Sorry misread your question, deleted my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the immediate problem of the grouping, you need to either group by the same expression or calculation of your new column, or use it from a derived table.

```
SELECT MonthYear
FROM (  SELECT Columns,
            CASE
            WHEN Date IS NULL
            THEN 'EMPTY'
            ELSE
                CASE
                WHEN Date = '1/1/1753'
                THEN 'UNAVAILABLE'
                ELSE CAST(MONTH(Date) as varchar(2))+
                     '/'+ CAST(YEAR(Date) as varchar(4))
                END
            END AS MonthYear
        FROM tbltablename) T
GROUP BY MonthYear
```

On the other hand, you shouldn't use `VARCHAR(MAX)` if its not necessary.

Comment: @steventnorris - In this case, *table*, but it doesn't means anything. You have to give an alias when using derived tables, so I named it `T`.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions says "variable", but I think you mean column alias.  Just FYI.

Using the actual column definition should work fine.  Untested, but this should do what you need:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
    WHEN Date IS NULL
    THEN 'EMPTY'
    ELSE
        CASE
        WHEN Date = '1/1/1753'
        THEN 'UNAVAILABLE'
        ELSE CAST(MONTH(Date) as varchar(MAX))+
             '/'+ CAST(YEAR(Date) as varchar(MAX))
        END
    END AS MonthYear
FROM tbltablename
GROUP BY
    CASE
    WHEN Date IS NULL
    THEN 'EMPTY'
    ELSE
        CASE
        WHEN Date = '1/1/1753'
        THEN 'UNAVAILABLE'
        ELSE CAST(MONTH(Date) as varchar(MAX))+
             '/'+ CAST(YEAR(Date) as varchar(MAX))
        END
    END
```

Comment: This does not work in standard sql, because the "as MonthYear" is not accepted in the group by statement.  Without the "as MonthYear" the statement should work.

Comment: Thanks, that was a careless cut and paste.  Edited.

Comment: This works. Little messy, but it works. I was hoping for some trim solution, but sometimes trim isn't possible. Also, I'll change the verbage to match column alias.

Comment: It does indeed bloat the code a bit.  If you want to ORDER BY the same expression, it's worse as you have it three times instead of two.  :)  The real downside is that you have to edit both if you make a change to either.

Comment: @PhilSandler - You can use the alias of the column on your `order by`, its not really necessary to write the same expression again

Comment: @PhilSandler you can generally order by column ordinal position instead. e.g. select a_very_complex_expression, another_very_complex_expression from table order by 1, 2

Comment: @Lamak You're right--I believe I was thinking of the WHERE clause.

Comment: @LordPeter: I would consider using an ordinal in an ORDER BY clause in anything but an adhoc query a very bad practice.  https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal