# How SELECT is executed before GROUP BY in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I was looking at the order in which the SQL is executed and I found out that it is:

```
FROM,
WHERE,
GROUP BY,
HAVING,
SELECT,
ORDER BY
```

But in the below query the "_index" is used in the GROUP BY, How is this possible?

```
SELECT COUNT(ab.id) AS count, COUNT(ab.id)/365.24 AS average,
    IF((SUBSTR(ab.begin, 1, 7) = '2014-08'), '2014-08-18 00:00:00.0 CEST',
    IF((SUBSTR(ab.begin, 1, 7) = '2014-09'), '2014-09-18 00:00:00.0 CEST',
    IF((SUBSTR(ab.begin, 1, 7) = '2014-10'), '2014-10-18 00:00:00.0 CEST',
    IF((SUBSTR(ab.begin, 1, 7) = '2014-11'), '2014-11-18 00:00:00.0 CET',
       '0')))) AS _index
FROM active_begin AS ab 
INNER JOIN asources AS a ON a.id = ab.asource AND a.unit IN (4, 3, 1) 
WHERE (1408226400000 <= ab.begin_time AND ab.begin_time < 1417388400000)
GROUP BY _index
```

PS. refr this for the order: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this (the [ability to use a column alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145123/group-by-column-alias) defined in the SELECT clause for the GROUP BY) is a probably non-standard extension that some databases allow (but not all).

You are supposed to repeat the exact definition again or wrap everything in a sub-select.

Lucky if your database lets you get away with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "order" to how SQL is executed.  The SQL optimizer can choose to execute the operations in any order it decides is best for the query.

There *is* an order to how the clauses are interpreted.  So, table aliases and columns are defined in the `from` clause -- this is interpreted first.  Then the subsequent clauses are interpreted.  In general, this explains why you cannot use a column alias defined in a `select` in a `where` clause, because the `where` clause is interpreted first.